# Azure Topics and subscriptions

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

In case of azure service bus queues two modes of operation like

a. Receive & Delete

b. Peek & Lock

are available.

And In Peek & Lock Mode there are different message settlement options like Complete, Abandon etc.

**Is it possible to write filters for subscriptions on Azure Portal or only through Code like C#?**

**What is the better way of creating Subscriptions and Topics , is it through Portal or Code?**

**Are there any modes like this for Topics and Subscriptions?**

**Are there any different message settlement options available for Topics and Subscriptions or  every Message will live till MessageTimeToLive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write filters for subscriptions on Azure Portal or only through Code like C#?

Filters are entities that are created on the broker side. You can use .NET SDK, you can use other language SDKs, or you can use the portal. You can use tools such as [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/) to achieve the goal.

> What is the better way of creating Subscriptions and Topics , is it through Portal or Code?

It depends on what you are doing. A quick verification/spkike, Portal is enough. If this is for a project, having in the code or Bicep script is more suitable.

> Are there any modes like this for Topics and Subscriptions?

Recieve modes are applied equally to queues and subscriptions. Topics are not for receiving but rather sending (publishing).

> Are there any different message settlement options available for Topics and Subscriptions or every Message will live till MessageTimeToLive?

Message settlements and TTL are not the same things. Settlement operations are invoked on messages by the processing code. TTL is a setting on entities to dead-letter messages. You'd benefit from reviewing the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions).